# Use PHP GET Method in URL?

Tags: php, html, get

I have index.php?stol=XY. Now I want to open gotovo.php with same 'stol' like in index.php. This is my code:

```
<a href="<?php "gotovo.php?stol=".$_GET['stol'] ?>">Link1</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing echo/print

Comment: You're missing an echo but there are a couple of other points to consider too.

1. You should use [`urlencode`][1] to prevent [XSS][2] attacks.
2. You will generate an E_NOTICE if $_GET['stol'] is not defined

Try this:

    <a href="gotovo.php?stol=<?php echo urlencode(isset($_GET['stol']) ? $_GET['stol'] : ''); ?>">Link1</a>


  [1]: http://php.net/urlencode
  [2]: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

Comment: Thanks. I know that, but I don't need [urlencode] because $_GET['stol'] will always be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<a href="<?= "gotovo.php?stol=".$_GET['stol'] ?>">Link1</a>
```

Comment: you're posting the exact answer of mine !

Comment: i was replying while you were replying... didn't see what you posted

Comment: No, you shouldn't, you can improve it,or delete it , there is no **should** ;)

Comment: well it was a pretty easy answer and i posted it 20 seconds later then yours... not very happy i got a down vote for it ;)

Comment: I upvoted your answer, and deleted mine ;)

Comment: oh, that was not needed though. Thanks dude, anyway i "improved" mine as well

Comment: your welcome, you are new, good luck with scores ;)